# Plot map No module named 'dbflib'

Tags: shapefile

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap,cm
import shapefile
import dbflib


import dbflib
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-398-b5a771049653>", line 1, in <module>
    import dbflib

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbflib'
```

Tried solutions suggested by other posts like install/uninstall tookit, doesn't work. Anyone has this kind issue?